# Run multiple processes of a Scrapy Spider

Tags: scrapy

I have a Scrapy project which reads 1 millions product IDs from database and then starts scraping product details based on ID from a website.

My Spider is fully working.

I want to run 10 instances of Spider with each assigned an equal number of product IDs.

I can do it like,

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_ids` and then divide it by 10 and then do

`SELECT * FROM product_ids LIMIT 0, N` and so on

I have an idea I can do it in Terminal by passing `LIMIT` in scrapy command like `scrapy crawl my_spider scrape=1000` and so on.

But I want to do it in Spider, so I just run my Spider only once and then it runs 10 another processes of same spider within spider.

Comment: In my opinion this logic should stay outside of the scrapy spider. Common way of doing this is to simply write a bash script to unix `split` a file that contains urls and then iterate through those files one by one and for each one startup a scrapy spider with an argument that is that file: `scrapy crawl -a file=xab`

Comment: I am good at PHP so I may write a PHP script for that ... :) good suggstion

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using **CrawlerProcess** helper class or **CrawlerRunner** class.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class Spider1(scrapy.Spider):
   # Your first spider definition

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(Spider1)
process.crawl(Spider1)
process.start()
```

It is running multi spiders in the same process not multiple processes.